# Xubuntu Panel Preferences Items tab shows wrong items

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

G'day there One & All,

Using Xubuntu 17.04 with no real issues that I've not caused myself, except this one that has been there since installation.

[image: Screenshot of Panel Preferences]

As you can see in the screenshot, the list of items in no way matches what I have installed. Worse, although you can't see it in the still shots, as I move my mouse around the titles of the items changes to something else again. Seems to choose titles from those listed, but still the wrong ones. To make matters worse this latter behaviour isn't constant. Sometimes they change sometimes they stay as is. I've searched high & low via our friend Mr Google, but without success.

If anyone has any ideas about how to fix this I'd be happy to hear them.

Thanks for reading,
Ken

P.S. I've tried swearing and cursing but that didn't work. I expect stamping my feet and having a temper tantrum will be equally effective :)

Comment: That's very interesting it looks that way.  Have you tried killing the panel and restarting it to see if that helps?  `pkill xfce4-panel` then `nohup xfce4-panel >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: Thanks for answering @Terrance :)

I hadn't tried that, I just ignored it and shutdown the pooter at the end of the day but it always came back up the same way. FYI, I just ran those 2 commands and they made no difference. I tried as normal user & with sudo but to no avail. 

According to my items list I have 2 lots of window buttons, 2 desktop switchers and 9 separators. However one of the window buttons (which has an icon that looks suspiciously like a running window) changes to a separator on mouseover. Quite strange really.